# Gunslinger Girl II Teatrino: Anime vs Manga

Tags: gunslinger-girl

I've heard from a lot of people that season 2 of the Gunslinger Girl anime adaptation is significantly more upbeat and brighter than the original, and loses the feeling of dark, morbid 'beauty', yet apparently, the second season follows the manga a lot closer.

Does the corresponding parts of the manga also have a more cheerful feel? (I only watched the anime, didn't read the manga)

Comment: Are you asking if the 2nd season of Gunslinger Girl reflect the manga, specifically with the "feeling"?

Comment: I'm asking does the second manga also have a more cheerful feel (than the first manga).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is **no**. I think so, because

> Many *gitai* (girls) died: Henrietta, Rico, Triela, Angelica, Beatrice, Silvia, ...

Answer (score -1):

I would like to point out that Gunslinger Girl -Il Teatrino-
style and colour scheme is a lot different from Gunslinger Girl. However it does still have it's darkness to it and it does follow the manga comics closer. Although I feel like it basically a remake of Gunslinger Girl but with a slightly brighter feeling to it.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references to support your answer.